# How to make pytest cases "runnable" in IntelliJ

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pytest

I want to write my test using pytest and to be able to run them (individually) in IntelliJ. I have pytest installed, along with (obviously) Python plugin for the IDE.

My test file (`tests/test_main.py`) looks like that:

```py
from app.main import sum_numbers


def test_sum_numbers():
    assert sum_numbers(1, 2) == 3
    assert sum_numbers(10, 20) == 30
    assert sum_numbers(1, 2, -3) == 0
```

Running `pytest` from terminal works perfectly. But IntelliJ seems to treat this as a regular file, there are no "run" icons before the declarations. Also, running the file from the IDE does nothing, as it is not treated as a test file.

What can I do?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here what you need to do:

1) Remove all the existing run configurations for your test file.

2) Make sure that **Preferences | Tools | Python Integrated Tools | Default rest runner** is set to **pytest**.

After that, you should see the run icon next to your test functions and right-clicking the test file should suggest running the pytest.
See the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/pytest.html) for more details.

Comment: Thank-you. Unbelievable how hard this was to track down!

Answer (score 0):

Open the source code, right-click and hit run using the option `run "filename.py"`.

IntelliJ will make the configuration for you and then you can click the run button after the configuration is made by the IDE.

Same thing for debug configuration.

Also, the IDE gives you the run button on individual tests after this.